# pack multiple google protobuf messages in single buffer in c

Tags: java, c, protocol-buffers

I am trying to send multiple protobuf's in single buffer from c language to java application which parses the request using parseDelimitedFrom api.

I tried packing multiple buffers in single msg and send but only one gets read at the java end.

I came to know, I need to write length of message before packing message to the buffer. But I don't know how to pack varint to buf in c.
Can anyone give me simple example here to pack multiple protobuf messages in single buffer in c language.

Comment: I am reading a lot on this on internet, seeing implementation of protobuf c but not able to get the clear idea about packing multiple messages into single buf. In c++ they have WriteVarint32 api, but there is nothing like in c to prefix length of message before packing message.

Comment: What does your .proto file look like?